# Cannot open server requested by the login

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to my Azure SQL database using pyodbc. The azure account that I am using is under the username xxxxxx@student.bham.ac.uk (my university account). When I try to connect to the database, I get the error

`Cannot open server "student.bham.ac.uk" requested by the login.  The login failed. (40532)`.

The credentials that I am using are correct. The error makes me think that it might be confusing my login for the database server? What does this error mean and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[This](https://stegriff.co.uk/upblog/using-email-addresses-as-login-usernames-on-azure-sql/) seems to work for me:

`If your SQL Database server is called myazureserver and your login is user@example.com, then you must supply your login as user@example.com@myazureserver.`

Comment: Bravo, this is great solution!

Comment: was also relevant with a "normal" username for me

Answer (score 5):

I recently suffered this same problem and I fixed it this way:

1. Go to your SQL Server resource on Azure
2. Go to "Firewalls and virtual networks"
3. Verify "allow Azure's service and resources accessing this server" is set as YES

[image]

Save changes and let up to 5 minutes to apply this changes.

Comment: Helped me straight away, thanks!

Comment: The security risk here is that the database is now open for connection from any Azure hosted service (not just your own tenant), bad actors included.

Answer (score 0):

What [Hdot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10622485/hdot) said works also for me

> If your SQL Database server is called myazureserver and your login is user@example.com, then you must supply your login as user@example.com@myazureserver.

but, worth to mention that if you use DBeaver, you must update USER and PASSWORD in 'Driver Properties' tab (instead of 'Main'). This can be really confusing.
[image]