# 'HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "dominio" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect with a database that has a @ login and this is confusing the connector, does anyone know how I make it find itself?

```
parametros = (
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
        'SERVER=localhost;'
        'PORT=1433;'
        'DATABASE=database;'
        r'UID={user123@dom.com.br};'
        'PWD=123456'
    )

try:
    conexao = pyodbc.connect(parametros)
    print("OK")
except TypeError:
    print(TypeError)

cursor = conexao.cursor()
```

Comment: Not sure `user123@dom.com.br` is actually valid as a SQL Authetication login. Is this actually a Windows Authentication login (coming from your AD domain which is called `dom.com.br`)? If so, you need to use `Trusted Connection` rather than a username and password to connect.

Comment: Duplicate? [Cannot open server requested by the login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824577/cannot-open-server-requested-by-the-login)

Answer (score 0):

I had once a similar problem , what help me, was doing it like this:

```
'UID={user123'+'@'+'dom.com.br};'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding authentication method at the end of connection string solved the issue in my case.
"Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;"